# Mock-up with WebFonts in Illustrator

Tags: fonts, web, adobe-illustrator

I am working on a web design that will be using webfonts from typekit or fontdeck, etc, but need to work with them in Illustrator to determine layouts, type combinations, sizes, etc. I cant find anywhere to download these fonts to use, so I am not sure the best way to go about sampling and testing the fonts before putting them in html/css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FontShop store has developed [an Illustrator extension](http://www.fontshop.com/plugin/) which lets you try the fonts in their store in your designs. Of course, if you like a font you’d need to buy it.

[image: FontShop extension]

Extensis (owner of the WebINK web font service) [has developed a similar extension](http://www.webink.com/webfontplugin) as well, but for Photoshop, which lets you try fonts from WebINK as well as Google Web Fonts.

Note that this extension is bundled with their Suitcase Fusion tool, and cannot be downloaded separately.

[image: Promo banner]